# Knockout binding throws an "Unable to process binding" exception in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

I've got a div that I'm trying to bind using Knockout using the following code:

```
<div data-bind="style: { height: ($('.someDiv').height() - 37) + 'px' }">...</div>
```

This works perfectly in Chrome, FF or IE11. Not sure it has been tested on IE9-10. But it fails on IE8, throwing a "Unable to process binding" exception.

Surprisingly, this works:

```
// without substracting 37
style: { height: ($('.someDiv').height() + 'px' }

// replacing 37 by the same computed value, doesn't matter if it ends up being 0
style: { height: ($('.someDiv').height() - $('.someDiv').height()) + 'px' }
```

But even more surprisingly, this fails too:

```
// replacing 37 by something (dumb) assuring a positive value
style: { height: ($('.someDiv').height() - $('.someDiv').height() + $('.someDiv').height()) + 'px' }
```

I'm kind of clueless here. Anyone knows anything about this ?

I'm using jQuery 1.11.1 and Knockout 3.1.0.

**EDIT:**

Ok I moved forward a little. It appears that the div `someDiv` is injected using a template in a custom binding. Therefore, if I do something like this around the binding:

```
console.log('before ko');
console.log('length:'+$('.someDiv').length);
console.log('$height:'+$('.someDiv').height());

ko.applyBindings(vm, $('#container').get(0));

console.log('after ko');
console.log('length:'+$('.someDiv').length);
console.log('$height:'+$('.someDiv').height());
```

The output is (both in IE8 and in Chrome):

```
before ko
$length:0
$height:null
after ko
$length:1
$height:762
```

So I guess something happens differently in Knockout during binding depending on the browser.

Comment: You should isolate the problem - I'm betting it's just that `$.height` fails in IE8. What version of jQuery are you using? Can you write a function or something that verifies the value of `$('.someDiv').height()` is what you'd expect it to be?

Comment: I'll try that and edit the question. But how can it be just `$.height`, if both working tests don't fail?

Comment: Is there any more information in the exception - I sometimes find if you dig further into the stack trace in knockout when binding errors happen, you often find a more meaningful message hidden away

Comment: @JamesThorpe I know, and this is the inner message...

Comment: Call me stupid if I've missed the obvious, but I don't see anything in the code you posted that justifies a Knockout binding. Also, your code doesn't contain any `data-bind` statements so it seems you aren't even using Knockout (and you don't have to, based on what you posted). So this problem should be totally unavoidable. Maybe you could add a bit more code (the actual binding) and tell us why you feel a Knockout binding is in order? (You're not binding against observables so you don't get anything extra for using a binding here).

Comment: @HansRoerdinkholder the posted code is the content of data-bind. As everything is working well on other browsers, I felt it was useless to bloat the question with anything irrelevant, as I know that the problem is here. The fact that everything is bound instead of just JS code is due to team policy (debatable, but plain fact). It's not even my code in the beginning :) But I'll add some more info when I get some.

Comment: I agree that this is weird and it'd be interesting to find out what IE8 is confusing itself with.  To isolate the problem, I'd move the style logic out of the binding you have and put it in a custom binding.  Then you can debug using browser debug tools.  If that works perfectly, then the problem is the string that IE8 gives knockout when it's parsing the data-bind attribute.  You can dive a little into the knockout internals to figure out what'd different between IE8 and Chrome.

Comment: I've just made the simple test that tries to simulate your problem. But seems it works good even in IE8. Maybe the problem is not about this binding? You can test my script: https://yadi.sk/d/npMK1aGubjyTQ

Comment: @f_martinez Indeed, it works. I edited my question with some new information.

Comment: @Milimetric Thanks for the advice, I'll try. Take alook at the edit, maybe it will ring a bell. A function Knockout uses that IE8 doesn't know about maybe ?

Comment: @X.L.Ant No Knockout is compliant back to IE6.  Something inside the binding is failing more than likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize my answer may not be a straight up answer, but since it may help you or others coming here anyways I'll still post it. Someone else may put down a more direct answer, who knows.

Your problem may be due to the fact that the logic enters KO as a string from the `data-bind` attribute, and is executed afterwards. It may help to keep this kind of logic out of the view, and put it in JavaScript code. In any case this will make it much easier to debug.

One KO feature available to do this is to use a custom bindingHandler. Here's how you could do that:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.fixHeight = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {        
        var h =  ($('.someDiv').height() - 37) + 'px';
        $(element).height(h);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings({});
```

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}

.someDiv {
    height: 123px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="someDiv">someDiv</div>
<div data-bind="fixHeight">...</div>
```

If I put my IE11 version into IE8 mode, the above works fine.

Again, I realize this may not be a straight up answer, but perhaps it's useful to folks anyways.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm not sure I understood WHY the problem comes up in this case, but I ended using a variation of this (valueAccessor containing both the jQuery selector and the offset).

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to edit my answer and include the changes you needed: it may help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution according to the answer here

[IE8 knockout error - Unable to process binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037759/ie8-knockout-error-unable-to-process-binding)

That truly because of incorrect value for style attribute in IE8.